# Why join table query always return none Flask-SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am beginner in Python and Flask- SqlAlchemy,I just cant figure out why the `query.join()` always just return `none`,even though my table have the exact data.

**Here is my table:**

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users_info"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String)

    user_device = db.relationship('Device', backref='user')


class Device(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user_device"  

    device_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
    private_token = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
```

**My goal** is to get `id`,`name` in `User` table and `private_token` in `Device` table give the `User.email` equal to some value in a single query.

**So here is what I tried:**

```
User.query.join(Device, User.id == Device.id)\
            .add_columns(User.id, User.name, Device.private_token)\
            .filter_by(User.email == data['email'])
```

I either use `filter()` or `filter_by()` in above query.But at the end it still return `none`.

So my question is,how to correctly join the table? What the way to achieve my goal above?

**EDIT:**

I tried add `.add()` and `.first()` in the above query,the result shown out is just `[ ]` after I print on console.

```
User.query.join(Device, User.id == Device.id)\
                .add_columns(User.id, User.name, Device.private_token)\
                .filter_by(User.email == data['email']).all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested the following and it works fine.

I created the models as follows and added some test data into the tables:

```
class User(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "user"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
name = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=True)
email = db.Column(db.String)
devices = db.relationship('Device', backref='user')

class Device(db.Model):
__tablename__ = "device"
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
uuser_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
private_token = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
```

Flask code like this:

```
@bp.route('/',  methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():

    devices = db.session.query(Device, User).join(User).filter(User.email == "test1@gmail.com").all()

    return render_template('main/home.html',
    devices = devices,
   )
```

To access the different attributes, create a loop in your template as follows:

```
{% for d in devices %}
  user id: {{ d.User.id }},
  name: {{ d.User.name }},
  private token: {{ d.Device.private_token }}
{% endfor %}
```

Create an dictionary object with user id, user name and token:

```
    x = {}
    for d in devices:
        x['user_id'] = d.UUser.id
        x['user_name'] = d.UUser.name
        x['private_token'] = d.Device.private_token
```

Comment: well, then just iterate over the devices object and only pick the 3 columns you need.

Comment: bro I use the query as u state,but the data return is like this  `{"data": [ ] }`

Comment: even though the data is exist in database

Comment: Are you sure data['email'] returns something valid to even use in the filter? Can you please test without the filter, so just Device.query.join(User).all() and print the output in a loop? If data exists in database this should return something.

Comment: now the return in console is like this `[<User 'None'>, <User 'None'>, <User 'None'>, <User 'None'>, <User 'None'>]`

Comment: after I remove the filter like this `devices = Device.query.join(User).all()`

Comment: I'll come back on this, let me test with real db and queries later today.

Comment: I just added more to my answer.

Comment: cause I using Flask-Restplus..So after the query,I just have to return `devices` to render it into my model..So I dont know how to do with for loop here..

Comment: instead of a loop in a template, you can loop in python code, create an object with the 3 fields you need, and return that object. I think a dictionary would work nicely?

Comment: ya seems pretty legit..Bro do you mind to provide me an example?Cause I am totally beginner in this,that will be well appreciated.

Comment: ooh this better be worth the points.. ;). See updated answer on dictionary object named x.

Comment: Ok let me try it later then come back to u